# How to check if one Element of an array matches or a part of an element of another array in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have a string array,

```
string[] numbers= {"one","two","last"}
```

I have another string array,

```
string[] variables={"string one","int two","string three"}
```

How can I get the elements of `variables` array that has the elements of `numbers` array.

As a result I have to get `"string one","int two"` elements.
And I have to remove those elements from `variables` array and store the remaining elements in a new array. So my new array should be like,

```
string[] newarray={"string three"}
```

I have used the following code. But could not get the exact result.

```
foreach (string variable in variables)
{
if(!variable .Contains(numbers.Any())
     {
       newarray.add(param);
     }
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] numbers= {"one","two","last"};
string[] variables={"string one","int two","string three"};
string [] variablesWithNumbers = variables.Where(t=>numbers
    .Any(u=>t.Contains(u))).ToArray();
string[] newarray = variables.Where(t=>!numbers
    .Any(u=>t.Contains(u))).ToArray();
```

here is the code in csharpad with print
http://csharppad.com/gist/989bbe7e439990bc1f993f46d3e64fe8

Answer (score 1):

You could do for example this:

```
var result = variables.Where(v=>v.Split(' ').Any(s=>numbers.Contains(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var newarray = variables.Where(v => !numbers.Any(n => v.IndexOf(n) >= 0).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq gives you so many ways to do this... One more path you could follow:

```
var itemsToDiscard = variables.Zip(numbers, (f, s) => !f.Contains(s)).ToArray();
var newArray = variables.Where((_, i) => itemsToDiscard[i]).ToArray();
```

Note that your problem is underspecified. Is position meaningful? Should the following find any match or not?

```
{"zero", "one", "two"}
{"string one","int two","string three"}
```

My proposed solution doesn't, but its far from clear if you want it to be so. In case order is unimportant, the equivalent code would be:

```
var itemsToDiscard = numbers.Select(n => variables.All(s => !s.Contains(n))).ToArray();
var resultWithoutPosition = variables.Where((_, i) => itemsToDiscard[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Position does not matter in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] numbers = { "one", "two", "last" };
string[] variables = { "string one", "int two", "string three" };
string[] newarray = variables.Where(v => !numbers.Any(n => v.Contains(n))).ToArray();
variables = variables.Where(v => numbers.Any(n => v.Contains(n))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = variables.Except(variables.Intersect(numbers, new ContainsComparer())).ToArray();
```

With this

```
private class ContainsComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {
  public bool Equals(string x, string y) => y.Contains(x);
  public int GetHashCode(string obj) => 0;
}
```